# Missing requirement osgi.wiring.package

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I get the `Missing requirement osgi.wiring.package ...` error when deploying a bundle, the missing package is coming from a library (a maven dependency) so the bundle has is in its `classpath`

What I understand is : when  using some class that comes from another `OSGI bundle` that bundle should declare it in its exports, and the user should declare it in its `imports`, but this is not the case, this is only a homemade library (not deployed to the osgi container, not even a bundle ) so there must be something I don't quite understand

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your bundle using and embedding the class has the import package in its Manifest. If this is the case then the OSGi framework tries to wire your bundle to another bundle that offers the package. As no other bundle offers it this will fail.

So you have to make sure that your bundle does not import the package and also correctly embeds the library.

Comment: it doesn't have the import package in its Manifest explicitly, it is probably the wildcard `*` ?